# How to set the Project ID for C++ storage client

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-cpp

How does one set the Project ID for the C++ Google Cloud Storage client?

The example code below throws an exception:

```
Permanent error SignBlob: Received HTTP status code: 404
```

If I set the environment variable, the code works.

```
set GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT=example_project_id
```

My goal is to not use environment variables. The Project ID is retrieved from a JSON configuration file.

```
#include "google/cloud/storage/client.h"

int main()
{
    namespace gcs = ::google::cloud::storage;
    using ::google::cloud::StatusOr;

    std::string project_id = "example_project_id";
    std::string bucket_name = "example_bucket_name";
    std::string object_name = "example_object_name";

    auto client = gcs::Client(
        google::cloud::Options{}
            .set<gcs::ProjectIdOption>(project_id)
    );

    StatusOr<std::string> signed_url = client.CreateV4SignedUrl(
        "GET",
        std::move(bucket_name),
        std::move(object_name),
        gcs::SignedUrlDuration(std::chrono::minutes(15)));

    if (!signed_url)
    {
        std::cout << signed_url.status().message() << "\n";
        throw std::move(signed_url).status();
    }

    std::cout
        << "The signed url is: " << *signed_url << "\n\n"
        << "You can use this URL with any user agent, for example:\n"
        << "curl '" << *signed_url << "'\n";
}
```

**Update 2023-05-27 after @coryan's answer.**

If I remove setting the client option `google::cloud::Options{}.set<gcs::ProjectIdOption>(project_id)`, clear the environment variable `GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT`, and set the `SigningAccount` to a valid service account email address that I have IAM permission to use, the following code works.

> However, that does not explain why `<gcs::ProjectIdOption>` does not
> work in the above example. While setting the environment variable `GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT` does enable the above example to work.

```
#include "google/cloud/storage/client.h"

void test1()
{
    namespace gcs = ::google::cloud::storage;
    using ::google::cloud::StatusOr;

    std::string project_id = "example_project_id";
    std::string bucket_name = "example_bucket_name";
    std::string object_name = "example_object_name";
    std::string sa_email = "example_service_account_email";

    auto client = gcs::Client();

    StatusOr<std::string> signed_url = client.CreateV4SignedUrl(
        "GET",
        std::move(bucket_name),
        std::move(object_name),
        gcs::SignedUrlDuration(std::chrono::minutes(15)),
        gcs::SigningAccount(sa_email)
    );

    if (!signed_url)
    {
        std::cout << signed_url.status().message() << "\n";
        throw std::move(signed_url).status();
    }

    std::cout << "The signed url is: " << *signed_url << "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Hey John. Do you want to get the project ID from your default (and personal) credential? If so, did you try to add a default quota project? `gcloud auth application-default set-quota-project XXXXXX`

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere - No, I want to set the Project ID in the c++ storage client. Yes, I have quota project correctly set. Currently, I have to set the environment variable `GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT` as the client is ignoring `google::cloud::Options{}.set<gcs::ProjectIdOption>(project_id)` and I do not know why.

Comment: I'm very bad at C++. But looking to the doc, you could use common option. Did you try this one? https://googleapis.dev/cpp/google-cloud-common/2.10.1/structgoogle_1_1cloud_1_1UserProjectOption.html

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere - thank you but that is not the correct setting. I am trying to tell the c++ storage client the Project ID, and besides setting the environment variable, I cannot find the technique. There is an options array, but the client is not picking up that option - `gcs::ProjectIdOption`.

Comment: I filed https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp/issues/11742 to fix the inconsistency around `ProjectIdOption`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think the project id is what is missing here?  I suspect this has nothing to do with the `ProjectIdOption` but with a missing default value for the signing service account email.  I have filed [#11740](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp/issues/11740) because the error message is not useful at all.

When the credentials are obtained from a service account key file, the client library create the signed URL locally, using the private key from the key file.

When the credentials are not a service account key file (user accounts, the GCE metadata service, whatever), the client library can use [IAM signBlob](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/signBlob) to sign the blob.

In the latter case it needs the service account email of the request to sign. For some credential types there is a default email associated with the credentials.  But sometimes there is none, or the value cannot be retrieved, for example, the metadata service may be unresponsive.

Without a default value for the service account email, the client library sends a request to `IAM signBlob` with an empty email address.  This results in a 404 error without additional details.

The application can provide a service account email, as shown in the `CreateV4SignedURL()` examples:

https://googleapis.dev/cpp/google-cloud-storage/latest/classgoogle_1_1cloud_1_1storage_1_1Client.html#a4600b6b5123e51283168ca2cf53926bf

If that is not the problem, please let us know and we will try to get this fixed.

Comment: If I set `GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT`, my example works. The current authentication ID is user credentials. I searched the Google library source code and I cannot find where the code reads back `<gcs::ProjectIdOption>`, so I think that is an unimplemented feature. I also ran the code in the Visual Studio debugger, and I could not see it processed either.

Comment: I logged the service account that the SDK is using: `service-<PROJECT_NUMBER@gs-project-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com`, so I incorrectly assumed that the identity was not the issue. That looks like a Google-managed service account identity. In another example, I create credentials from a service account and that works.